# Convergent subsequences in a compact metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, compactness

Let $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a compact metric space and let $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ be two sequences such that $\lim(u_n - v_n) = 0$.

Show that there exist subsequences of $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ such that they have the same limit ?

I think we would need the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem but I clearly don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

As a sequence in a compact,
$(u_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $ (u_{\phi(n)}) $ with $L$ as its limit.
but

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(v_{\phi(n)}-u_{\phi(n)})=0$$

and

$$v_{\phi(n)}=(v_{\phi(n)}-u_{\phi(n)})+u_{\phi(n)}$$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}v_{\phi(n)}=0+L=L$$